# Name for a four-dimensional "plane" in a six-dimension space

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

Suppose there is a 4D "plane": if the "plane" is in a 5D space, then a formal name for it is "hyperplane", as the hyperplane always has dimension $n-1$.

What if it is a 4D "plane" in a 6D space?

I think we can use the term "planar manifold of dimension 4". But are there any simpler names?

Comment: I'm assuming you are talking about vector spaces? In that case, there is no standard name for this, but you could just say something like a 4 dimensional subspace, or codimension 2 subspace.

Comment: I would call it "vector subspace" (or "affine subspace" if it needs not contain the origin) and I would specify either its dimension or its codimension, whichever is more relevant.

Comment: @Gae.S. So hyperplane is an affine subspace with codimension 1?

Comment: @HighGPA Usually, yes.